# Undefined variable & Trying to get property of non-object on prepend button to images Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function

I prepend a button to my WordPress images in my single-posts to share the images on Pinterest. The function works fine so far but i get the following notices.

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: post in **...functions.php** on
> line **2443**
>  **Notice**:  Trying to get property of
> non-object in **/functions.php** on line **2443**

The mentioned line of the notice is the one which starts with `$(this).prepend(..`

**Any idea how to solve this issue?**

Used Function:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('figure').prepend(function(){
        var pinurl = $(this).children('img').attr('data-original'); // with lazy load
        // var pinurl = $(this).children('img').attr('src'); // default
        $(this).prepend( '<a class="share-pinterest-btn" title="Pinterest" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&media='+pinurl+'&is_video=false&description=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_excerpt()); ?>" onclick="window.open(this.href, \'mywin\',\'left=50,top=50,width=600,height=350,toolbar=0\'); return false;">Pin it</a>');
    });
});
</script>

<?php else : ?>

     // something else

<?php endif; ?>
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<figure id="post-881 media-881" class="align-none"><img alt="" data-original="http://teststestests.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/1.jpg" class="loaded" src="http://teststestests.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/1.jpg"></figure>
```

Comment: So where did you define the `$post` object?

Comment: I tried to put `global $post;` into the function - but no luck. If you mean something else - im unfortunatley not able to fix it - still reading wordpress docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(is_single()) : 
global $post;
?>
```

then your javascript code

Comment: perfect - thank you so much! I already placed the `global $post;` inside the function with no luck :)